# Deploying frontend and backend to OVH Server with FileZilla

Tags: server, production-environment, ovh, deploying

I have VUE JS frontend app and NEST JS backend application. I would like to deploy both applications to my ovh server. But i have some problem deploying my API Nest JS. Can anybody give me help with this ?

So in /www/ folder i have my VUE JS application and in /www/api/ i have my API Nest JS.

There is my .htaccess file configuration :

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

What i'm doing wrong here ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When i call url   https://domain_name/login   for frontend application it works. But when i want to do GET Request and i call   https://domain_name/api/users/get/all    i'm getting 404 error, page not found